# call one action method from another action method with changed url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one action link button in view like below:

```html
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Article", "Edit", "Article", new { id= data.ID }, null)
```

When i click on this button process is hitting "Edit" action method with id as parameter and changing the url like "localhost/Article/Edit/2".

In this action method i am updating database and i have to call another action method from this. For that i used the code like below:

```html
return RedirectToAction("Result", "Article", new {id= data.ID });
```

This is hitting "Result" action method but after that url is not changing like this: "localhost/Article/Result/2" and current url is the above url, It is not changing only.

How do i make the same?

Comment: when user click the first action link - are you binding a click event then call ajax on that action link url via jquery?

Comment: Hi Alan, I have found my answer and updated here. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer like when i am calling result action method in that i was returning edit view only due to that that page was still opened in edit view. Now i have created result view to redirect to this view after hitting result action method.

Comment: I think this is not a right answer for above ques so use comment for this instead of answer

Comment: I have found my answer like when i am calling result action method in that i was returning edit view only due to that that page was still opened in edit view. Now i have created result view to redirect to this view after hitting result action method.